# How to get subslice of Options instead of Option of subslice?

Tags: rust, slice, option-type

From [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get), `get` method, given a range, returns an `Option` of subslice which is `None` if range is out of bounds:

```rust
let v = [10, 40, 30];
assert_eq!(Some(&[10, 40][..]), v.get(0..2));
assert_eq!(None, v.get(0..4));
```

Is there a way to get a slice of `Option`s instead, so `v.get(0..4)` would return a subslice with `Some(10), Some(40), Some(30), None` values?

Comment: No. Data layout would be incompatible.

Comment: You have to have somewhere stored "array" (in a contiguous place in memory) of `Option<T>`, but you only have an "array" of `T`.

Comment: You could write a function that would allocate such array as a `Vec` and return it instead, but I don't see any use case for something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a slice, because a slice *always* has to refer to a *contiguous* memory region with items of the exact same layout. Your storage doesn't store additional `None` before and after the values that an out of bounds slice could refer to, and neither do `T` and `Option<T>` always have the same layout, so a slice is out of the question.

Instead you could create an iterator over `Option<&T>` that you can `collect` if you want to:

```rust
    let iter = (0..4).map(|i| v.get(i));
    let opt: Vec<Option<&i32>> = iter.collect();
    assert_eq!(opt, vec![Some(&10), Some(&40), Some(&30), None]);
```

For `Copy` types it might be more efficient to copy the items instead of taking references for example with [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied)